# Convert JSON to Array OR JSON to XML in VB.NET ONLY

Tags: xml, vb.net, json

I have searched for the answer to this for a few hours with no successful code.

How can I convert a JSON string to an array OR a JSON string to XML in VB.NET?  I know how to do this in C#, as I have read dozens of articles on it, however, I am unable to figure out how to achieve the same result in VB.NET.

I'm using the System.Web.Script namespace via System.Web.Extensions.dll (from Microsoft).

I'm willing to use an additional DLL file if needed.

Comment: Show us your C# code; almost all C# can be trivially converted to VB.Net.

Comment: This is the code I have been using in C# - http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c/

Comment: What problem are you having in VB.Net?

Comment: I don't know the correct VB.Net syntax of `var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(jsonText);`

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(jsonText)
```

[Generic types in VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio puts a line under "Dynamic" and says "Type expected."  Any ideas?

Comment: VB.Net doesn't have `Dynamic`; you need to use `Object` instead.  `Option Strict Off` will make it easier to work with.

Comment: Almost there, now it says this error: `Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

Comment: Figured it out with the help of @SLaks.  Here is what I ended up using: `Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()` then `Dim table = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(str)` and finally `table(0)("key name")`